# Adding stats as a migration target

Tags: discussion, migration, close-reasons

It would be nice to add https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as a migration target:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that would definitely be a good idea; we get a lot of questions that belong there.

The trick is that sites only get migration paths (in or out) after they graduate fully. The reasoning behind this is that beta sites are still figuring out their scopes, and it would be bad to send a question away forever with no way to reopen it at the source site.

Moderators can migrate things anywhere, but only if the question is less than 60 days old. If we get pro-tem mods in time, we could consider sending any good-but-definitely-off-topic questions away.

People might also want to migrate to [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), but it's still in public beta and is therefore not guaranteed to stick around. Migrations to beta sites are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258601/295684).

Answer (score 1):

I think we should have first the list of questions which are off-topic here, and on-topic there. If we've enough number of them, the migration target probably can be added later on. For now you can flag each question for moderation, so it can be migrated manually when accepted.

However as far as I've checked, there are only 73 questions tagged with [artificial-intelligence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) on Stat.SE where 1/3 of them are still unanswered (24), so I believe some questions about artificial intelligence probably are better suited here. Unless they're specifically related to [machine-learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) where, again, 40% of them are unanswered which make us think where they really belong.

On the other hand, using/programming/implementing AI, at the same time doesn't make me expert on statistics aka cross-validation/rotation estimation model, which to be honest, I don't know nothing about.

And it's not only me:

> statistical learning is not the path to AI (Artificial Intelligence)

Source: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/I-once-heard-statistical-learning-is-not-the-path-to-AI-Artificial-Intelligence-what-are-the-arguments-that-support-this-statement-claim).

Comment: "1/3 of them are still unanswered (24), so I believe some questions about artificial intelligence probably are better suited here" -> unfortunately ~60% of all questions on CV are unanswered, so that doesn't mean that AI isn't ok there, just that we need more experts on CV.

Comment: The main idea behind add CV as a migration target would be to have more understandable closure flags.